# Shortening a SQL query to check entries have specfic values or don't exist

Tags: sql, oracle, hql

I have a table of tags where each row has column "name" and "value". Names are unique.

I have a (fixed) set of names (although over time I may need to add to the set - it's OK to edit the query when that happens)

I need to check that for every name in the set, either there is no row with that name, or if a row exists then the corresponding value is one of two differnt fixed strings (say "ONE" and "TWO")

I also have a limit on the length of the query - it's stored itself in a DB table and must be <2048 characters long.

For each tag, I currently use something like the query below, which works, but when I have more different names in my set, it quickly exceeds the maximum length.

Is there a different (shorter) way of doing it? Query to get the subset of tag names that exist, and then check all of those have one of the two values?

Ideas (that I don't know how to do in SQL): Count the number of tags that have names in my fixed list. Count the number of tags that have names in my fixed list and one of the two permitted values, compare the counts

Get all distinct values of tags in my fixed list. Check the distinct values are a subset of my permitted values list

DB is Oracle, but I'd like a solution that also works with MariaDB. I can use HQL or SQL.

```
and (
    NOT exists(
      from
        tags T
      where
        T.name = 'FOOBAR'
    )
    OR exists(
      from
        tags T
      where
        T.name = 'FOOBAR'
        and T.value in('ONE', 'TWO')
    )
  )
```

Comment: Do you need to write a constraint on the table, or just a query that you can use to find violations, whenever you choose to run it? Separately: it seems it would be best to keep a separate table of just those names for which this condition must be satisfied, and reference that table in the constraint (or in the query you may use now and then for verification).

Comment: Just a query, and i can't add tables (well, I can, but it's a lot of trouble). I;'m fine with having to writ the list of names in the query itself.

Comment: Maybe I'm over thinking it. Will `NOT EXISTS (from tags t where t.name IN ('NAME', 'ANOTHER', 'ONEMORE') and t.value NOT IN ('ONE','TWO'))` do it? I should tryi it.

Comment: If you can't have a table, so you must write the list of names to check right there in the query, as the list grows how are you going to keep the whole query below 2048 characters?

Comment: As mathguy is suggesting go ahead and pay the price (trouble) to have a validation table added. While it may be some trouble now not doing so will be much more trouble if you need to figure out how to change the query every time the requirement changes.

Comment: You're quite correct in the long term, I should add a table. But it's a pain. For now, I'd like to just be able to use a longer hardwired list.

Answer (score 2):

This should accomplish the same goal:

```
and (
    NOT exists(
      from
        tags T
      where
        T.name = 'FOOBAR'
      and
        T.value not in ('ONE','TWO')
)
```

ie. it will filter records where `T.name = 'FOOBAR'` unless the `value` is in your set.

Not sure if it will save enough space though.

Comment: Thanks. But it's probably not short enough still. It would keep me OK for a while, though.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul mathguy's comment is the only long term solution for that.  Store the list of values in another table, then change the line above to `and T.value not in (SELECT value from ValuesTable)`.  It's easier to manage a table of values anyway, so it's a positive solution all around.  Obviously you would need to be able to create the table though, but I don't see a way around that.

Comment: Yes, correct in the long term.  It will be a long time before I have more than 2048 characters in my list of fixed names, though. There are also constraints on what my users can do - they can edit the query, but udating the table will be difficult for them

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul Gotcha. I'm glad this helps for now, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
where nvl((select max(t.value) from tags t where name ='FOOBAR'), 'ONE') in ('ONE', 'TWO')
```

Comment: Better, but still quite long.